Relativistic mass of a closed system
Consider a Large Hadron Collider placed in space. Arrangements were made to collect the energy required to run the machine from starlight.  Some proton particles are inserted inside it. When the device is operated, let's imagine that once the proton particles started moving at 99.9999999% the speed of light. My question is will increased  kinetic energy of protons add mass to the machine and the total rest mass of the hadron collider system increase? And will its gravitational attraction also increase?

Relativistic mass is an obsolete concept no longer used in any serious physics text right now.

@DonAl. How about explaining what should be used instead of "relativistic mass" and "rest mass"?

The inirtial and gravitational mass are equivalent, it is a question of the interaction time between fields and particles (delayed or dilated time) which is included in the equation $f=\gamma ma$ which is a principle...,either $m=\gamma m_{0}$ or $t=\gamma t_{0}$, $E^{2}=m^{2}+p^{2}$ or $s^{2}=r^{2}+l^{2}$

To be consistent with physical liturature, the last equation is written $r^{2}=s^{2}+l^{2}$ with $s=c\tau$,$r=\gamma \tau$,$l=\gamma v\tau$. The simplest example is to shoot at a target with bullets (one bullet per second), the target will receive a different flow of bullets depending on distance and direction.(if we replace $\tau$ by $m$ , we find the energy equation .

@md2perpe Instead of "relativistic mass" and "rest mass" you discard the former and use simply "mass" for the latter.

@DonAl. I meant that you could explain that to Akhtar, and perhaps also answer his question instead of just complaining about "relativistic mass" being an obsolete concept.

Yeah, people are overzealous about relativistic mass. "Relativistic mass" of constituent particles can contribute to rest mass of a composite system, which is precisely what this question is about. It's not an obsolete concept in that sense.

@Sten. I certainly understand reserving mass to mean "rest mass" for elementary particles, but I think that it can still be useful to talk about "relativistic mass" and "rest mass" in other cases. Especially it's important to understand that energy has inertia and that adding energy to an object increases its inertia, no matter if the energy manifests as increased temperature or increased speed. Therefore I somewhat oppose those who always scream "$E=mc^2$ is incorrect; the correct is $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2.$

Yes, the mass of the device is increased, but that happens already when energy is stored in the device. Whether the energy is stored in a chemical battery, a capacitor or as kinetic energy of protons doesn't matter. Energy and mass are basically the same thing; that's what $E=mc^2$ means. (But nowadays, "mass" is usually used for the energy in the rest frame of an object.)
Also the device's gravitational attraction will increase. According to the theory of general relativity, the source of gravity is primarily the density of energy.

You have to be careful. If rest mass $M_1$ of the system is when it is first placed in space, $M_2$ is the mass after the starlight is collected and the energy stored in the machine (with batteries or capacitors), and $M_3$ is after the stored energy is discharged and the protons are at full speed, then:
$$M_1 < M_2, ~~M_2=M_3$$
The mass increases as a result of the solar energy input, and thus both the inertia and gravity of the machine increase. But transferring the energy internally from stored electrical energy to kinetic energy has no effect on the overall energy content (aka mass).

If you have a nonrotating point mass as is the Schwarzschild metric its gravitational mass $\rm M$ is just its irreducible mass $\rm \mathcal{M}$, so $\rm M=\mathcal{M}$ when the spin $\rm a=0$.
If you spin that up it becomes a ring and you get the Kerr metric where $\rm M=2 \mathcal{M}^2/\sqrt{4 \mathcal{M}^2-a^2}$, so the gravitational mass $\rm M$ becomes more than the irreducible mass $\rm \mathcal{M}$.
In that terms you would get a naked singularity when $\rm a>M$ or in terms of the irreducible mass $\rm a>\mathcal{M} \sqrt{2}$, but you get the point.
We can also examine the gravitational contribution of a mass $\rm M$ in orbit around a Schwarzschild black hole, which is $\rm E=M c^2 \sqrt{(1-r_s/r)/(1-v^2/c^2)}$, so that depends on its local velocity $\rm v$ (relative to the barycenter) and position $\rm r$.
In Newtonian language the latter would be the potential energy which also contributes to the total gravity of a system in relativity, so it's not only the local relativistic mass.
If the kinetic energy is equivalent to the escape velocity the kinetic and potential terms add to $0$ (or in other words multiply to a factor of $1$) and only the rest mass remains as a contribution to the total energy of the system.
